# How can I stop navigator (HTML5) from being undefined when running in node

Tags: html, node.js, webrtc

I'm receiving and error when running a webrtc node service. I get an error when  trying to use navigator. Here is the error when running 
`node client.js`:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.webkitGetUserMedia
   ^

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
```

I am using angular and node to run the file that has webrtc in it. Here is my setup:

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 10.16.0
Angular: 8.0.0

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.1
@angular/cdk                      7.0.4
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@angular/http                     6.0.9
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

and here is my client.js code:

//checks if the browser supports WebRTC

```
function hasUserMedia() { 
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.webkitGetUserMedia 
      || navigator.mediaDevices.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.msGetUserMedia; 
   return !!navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia; 
}

if (true) { 
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.webkitGetUserMedia
      || navigator.mediaDevices.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.msGetUserMedia;

   //get both video and audio streams from user's camera 
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream) { 
      var video = document.querySelector('video'); 

      //insert stream into the video tag 
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); 
   }, function (err) {}); 

}else {
   alert("Error. WebRTC is not supported!"); 
}
```

I started to add navigator.mediaDevice because of a post I saw about a new WebRTC version. I'm not entirely sure if I need it for every method.

If the community thinks WebRTC isn't the preferred way to go, let me know. I'm still trying to figure out the best option for a live streaming application. But I thought WebRTC would be the best.

Comment: Why not replace `if(true)` with something like `if(typeof navigator !== 'undefined')`?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake. 

But, navigator should be defined based on HTML5

Comment: There's no such thing as HTML5 when running in Node.

Comment: Node is not a browser. There's no `document`, no `window`, no `navigator`. You can shim in a navigator with a library if you really need one, but it's probably better to remove that dependency.

Comment: This is why I'm trying to understand why I'm even getting the error. I understand that node is not browser. So I should really just be running the client.js file in my angular project..? Doesn't make sense to run the client file on the server side...?

Comment: No, you should not be running javascript code that is specific for the client (anything with `document`, `window` or `navigator` won't work, however there is code that will work both on client and server). If you want WebRTC on the node.js server, you will need a library that implements it ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=node.js+webrtc)).

Comment: Does your server have a webcam and a mic? Who's at the other end? The data-center's maintenance guy?

Comment: @Theraot where is the most optimal place to run it?

Comment: something tells me WebRTC isn't old.

Comment: The user interacts with the client. The client interacts with the server. Node is a server. It's job is to answer the client's questions so that the client can show something to the user. Node is listening to requests from the client and responds with data from, say, a database or a file server. You use it to implement a REST service or an HTTP server. I think you're thinking about everything a bit backwards. This article may be helpful: https://www.sitepoint.com/node-js-is-the-new-black/

Comment: If you want to use WebRTC to communicate between the node.js server and a browser client, you need WebRTC on both. It won't be the same code, because you - ideally - will be using the browser implementation of WebRTC, but that is not available on the server. Thus, you will need a custom library that implements WebRTC for the Node.js server. However, note that if you only want WebRTC for communication between clients (each on their broswer) - for which WebRTC a great solution - then you do not need to run WebRTC on the server at all. It all depends on what is it you want to do.

Comment: I get the idea. I would like for WebRTC to be used in node.js. Wouldn't happen to know of any good guides out there for this do you? I've been searching for "node.js and webrtc" but no luck with any of the links.

Comment: Got it working locally. WebRTC really is simple and powerful. The overall documentation when googling is not so great. I'm sure this will change in the next couple of years.